# Secure Connection from DMZ Web Server to Internal Web Server

Tags: iis, .net

We have a .NET web service running on an internal IIS web server that allows outside organizations to send us documents that are then automatically filed on our Sharepoint server (running off the same server).  We would like to move the web service to our DMZ IIS web server and then have it talk to our Sharepoint server on the LAN.  In order to talk to the Sharepoint site, the web service is currently running in an application pool with the domain user identity.  The DMZ web server is not part of the domain so how would I authorize a user from it to Sharepoint?

Comment: Configure another server in reverse proxy ?

Comment: I'm not sure that would work in this case because the .NET web service is only accepting documents to be posted and is not returning anything other than a result status to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, web server can be in DMZ, when IIS is connecting to the internal application that communication can be on a secure port , you can authorise application user to application using the secure ldap

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/526964)

Comment: This question is also almost 7 years old at this point and no longer relevant.